# How Could I Use a Deployed Rails 4 App Offline and Sync it When I Want?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, webserver

I am developing a Rails App that serves as a cash register, sales recorder and ticket printer for each purchase for many stores of the same franchise.

The problem is that it must be able to run offline in case the internet goes down at any given time, at any store location, so that customer service does not get affected.

Is there a way to run the Rails App offline and sync it with the server after the connection has been re-established?

Or even operate it offline and sync it at the end of the day?

Does it require a specific database?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Depends. Sync is hard. You really don't want to go down this road unless it's absolutely unavoidable.

Comment: @tadman I'm willing to go down that road, unless there is an alternative, but the situation requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there's no reason that you can't do this.  I have done it, and it actually works pretty well, if you're careful about how you design the application.

Other than those, the things to be aware of are:

- Javascript libraries, such as jQuery, that you would need to ensure get loaded from your public directory, rather than from a CDN
- Rails comes with SQLite, and that works great for offline (and small-scale) functionality.  You can use local database servers for Postgres or MySQL (or anything that you can install locally) if you prefer.
- Images, fonts, and other design assets should be available locally, as well, which can be tricky if you have online image or font resources that you want to use (e.g. Google restricts offline usage of their font resources)

Testing offline behavior is pretty easy, as well.  Put it on a laptop and turn off the Wifi.  You'll know pretty quickly if that works.

For file sync between the offline app and the main server, you have your choice of technology and data formats.  You can implement REST-style sync APIs, low-tech FTP push, or even rsync.  Data formats could easily be JSON (the current princess of structured data storage), well-established CSV, or even (shudder) XML.

There should be no surprises in building an offline application, and you'll have all the tools and resources that Rails makes available to you, except the ability to arbitrarily load resources from the internet.

Comment: From what I understood first of all I have to deploy the app both locally and online. And for the sync(REST API is my choice) I have to allow the local app to connect to the online app API.

Does this make them slightly different, or are they exactly the same app?

Comment: That should be really be no problem.  It's just a design consideration.  Rails won't prevent you from doing that at all.  I have done this, so if there are any questions that you have, please make sure to ask.

Comment: All right, please correct me if I misunderstood: 

1.- I deploy the app both locally and online.
2.- Connect them via REST API.
3.- Use the local app and it will always update the online one while it has internet access.
4.- When it is offline and gets reconnected it will push all the changes to the online app.
5.- MySQL(the database I use) will keep updated at the end of the day when the local app is reconnected to the internet.

Comment: This can be the same app or different apps, depending on the functional requirements.  With a store franchise system, it's often the case that the "register" mode is exclusively used by one type of employee, and all of the other functions by another.  You might find it easier to build a separate application, or it might be better to simply make it a role-based option after login.

Comment: Regarding sync, you will have to sync both directions, up and down, as you'll need to allow the local system acquire new products, prices, users, etc, and then you'll also need to send sales and other transactional information back to the central location.  It simply takes planning and a good understanding of the specific requirements.

Comment: Excellent, this solves my doubts, you've been extraordinarily helpful. I'll get on to it, thank you Michael.